# How Do I Get The Names Of All The Entry Points In user32.dll?

Tags: dll, entry-point, rundll32

I am experimenting around with *rundll32.exe* and *user32.dll*. For example, to lock my workstation I type:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

I would like to try other commands (entry points) in *user32.dll* but I don't know what they are. Is there some way to determine all the entry points in *user32.dll* or more generally in any dll? And also what are valid arguments to the dll function call?

Note, what I am trying to do ultimately is to open the start menu using rundll32.exe. If anyone knows which dll/entry point will cause the start menu to popup please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, running random functions from user32.dll will just crash -- they are intended to be called from a program. If you want to pop up the Start menu, it is significantly more complicated.

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is add a sub menu to the right-click popup context menu that appears when you right-click the desktop. I am playing around with doing this using registry settings but I am thinking its not possible to do what I want with a simple .REG file. I may have to programatically modify the registry or something else.

Comment: What does adding a pop-up menu to the desktop context menu have to do with opening the Start menu? What does it have to do with rundll32?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31d242h4(v=vs.110).aspx
where this question is gracefully answered, and its relevance acknowledged.
Opening a Visual Studio command window will put dumpbin on the path, and user32.dll
is in \Windows\system32. You could then look up args in msdn on the web.